# VS Code does not suggest user snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code

I define some user snippet but it does not list in suggestion. How to show user snippets in suggestion list?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have defined a user snippet for the php language. In VS Code you need to save the file with .php extension then you will get suggestions on pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Pressing tab will work as you have already set the 'editor.tabCompletion' as 'true'. 
`"editor.tabCompletion": true`